# ffmpeg dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmp3lame.0.dylib

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

I am getting this error when running ffmpeg on OSX Yosemite 10.10.2

```
ffmpeg
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmp3lame.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

How do I install / compile libmp3lame.0.dylib ? ffmpeg was installed using homebrew

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved this by running the following commands in terminal (I use the package manager [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) for managing Unix based tools under OSX)

```
brew uninstall lame
brew install lame
sudo brew link lame
```

Comment: The quality of this answer is very low. Please improve it by including some content such as steps or details how this is the proper answer.

Comment: You should not need sudo for this and Homebrew should have refused to work with sudo. I think the linking step isn't even required.

Comment: `brew uninstall lame` failed because I already had ffmpeg installed.  It told me I had to do `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies lame` which I did, and then `brew install lame` and it worked fine.  I did not need to use sudo.

Comment: didn't help....

Answer (score 1):

If ffmpeg was installed using Homebrew, I suppose libmp3lame was also installed using Homebrew. Probably some links were lost during OS X upgrade.

Try relinking libmp3lame running

```
brew unlink lame && brew link lame
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by uninstalling Anaconda. My error had an extra message that referenced a system path involving Anaconda.
I had the library already installed in both the Anaconda environment and the System environment. However, I think that the Anaconda installation was corrupted and was causing the error.